# Let f(x) = 2x. What is i. $f(\mathbb{Z})$? ii. $f(\mathbb{N})$? iii. $f(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functions

I am struggling with this question and really need hints I wish if there is an upload file button here so that I can upload my solution to the question for check, since i faced difficulties typing symbols here.

Comment: What have you tried? I have a hint for the case $\mathbb{Z}$. If $n$ is an integer, what can you say about $2n$? (There's only one thing you can say for sure about it.) The same hint works for $\mathbb{N}$: If $k$ is a natural number (i.e., a positive integer), what can you say about $2k$?

Comment: Finally, in the case of $\mathbb{R}$, there is a hint that can be given, but might be a bit cryptic. If I give you a real number, you can divide it by $2$ and get another real number. Notice I didn't say anything about what real number I have given you, so what might that tell you about $f(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking that given $f(x)=2x$ what is the image of $\mathbb{Z}, $$\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ under $f$ then we can basically just plug in

Well, $$f(\mathbb{Z})=\{....-4,-2,0,2,4....\}$$

$$f(\mathbb{N})=\{0,2,4,....\}$$ depending on your definition of naturals it might not contain zero

And $$f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$$ as f is a bijective function on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: can we write f(z)={...-4,-2,0,2,4...x is an element of Z}?

Comment: That doesn't specify the involvement of $x$ in your set. Instead, write
$$f(\mathbb{Z}) = \{2x\mid x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$